# Default group is not imported from Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory

I am developing an application that imports users and groups from Active Directory.

`Base: CN = ivan ivanov, CN = Users, DC = perimetrix, DC = ru, Filter: (& (objectCategory = user) (objectClass = user) (userPrincipalName = *))`

The Domain Users default group is not imported. However, if a user is in 2 or more groups on a domain controller, then the default group in which the user is composed is imported correctly.

If the user is only in the default group, then it is not imported.

How to import a default group?

Comment: Please also paste some code, now there is no way to tell what you are doing, and might be doing wrong

Comment: Check why `Domain User is a Primary Group`, and how to detect the same using filter `PrimaryGroupID -eq 513`: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesteve/2017/10/04/group-membership-isnt-consistent-in-ad-users-and-computers/

Answer (score 0):

The primary group is a bit different. It doesn't use the `member` attribute like normal group membership. The `primaryGroupId` attribute of the user contains the RID of the group (the RID is the last portion of the SID, after the last dash). In most cases, that is `513`, the RID of the built-in `Domain Users` group.

You will have to show your code so we can see what you mean by "imported". It might be a quirk of the specific implementation you are using that isn't checking the primary group all the time.

I did write an article where I showed [how to get a user's primary group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html#the-primary-group). It's written in C#, but the principle is the same regardless of the language.